# Manage Splash screen activity and background tasks on android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, background-process

I have two activities. One splash and other the main activity which loads fragments as pages. Currently my splash does no background tasks, it just sit pretty and transition to main activity which does following background tasks.

1. set up admob ads
2. Request a data file from the server
3. Decript encryption key
4. Loads some images from disk to display
5. Set up google leader-board or sign in if the user is not sigh in.

My question how to delegate some of these tasks to splash screen? And how do I pass these complex objects between activities (can I use static variables)

At the moment I am contemplating to ditch the splash activity and use main activity to show the splash image in that. But the main activity layout has banner adds so not sure how to cover entire screen with the image.

Please help!

**My main activity**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_above="@+id/fragment_ad"/>

         <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_ad"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            class="com.controllers.AdFragment" />

    </RelativeLayout>


public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    /** Duration of wait **/
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 2000;


    String data = "";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);



       data = getIntent().getDataString();
        /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity 
         * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */

                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                if(data != "")
                    mainIntent.putExtra(Utils.Challenge_DATA_CODE, data);
                SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);


    }
```

Comment: Can you show the XML of the main activity. I don't think you should have a problem covering it with an image

Comment: I have updated the question. You mean go for the second option, use variable to show hide layouts (1 - relative layout with splash image 2- layout with current layout) using a timer?

Comment: The solution is the one that will fit your needs. Placing an image hiding your main activity is easy, though you should consdier it it suits you.

Comment: What I want to achieve is do some background work while splash is going on. currently nothing is been done, while main activity load does all heavy lifting. any workarounds?

Comment: Is your splash screen a simple activity?

Comment: SplashActivity included now in the question. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Have a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create a Service in the backgound and executes some tasks for the foreground Activities, like below :

1) the application starts the splash screen, this activity starts a Service which starts to execute some background tasks.

2) the splash activity exits due to time out or user's touching, the main activity shows and check the progress of the background tasks executed by the Service.

3) just keep in mind that the backgound tasks may get finished before the main activity shows.

@pats,

As for how to transfer the data from the Service to the main activity, you can use the View/Data controller model, means there is a singleton manager stores the complex data produced by the Service, then provides these data to the main acitivty as needed.

Hope these help.

Comment: Although I say they are background tasks, the work they do is directly related to main activity. I mean they create objects with state info. How do I transfer these complex objects to main activity.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should split the workload like this:

1. Data and work you must have before the user can use the app
   should be executed in the splash screen and off-course you should
   wait for it to finish before continuing to the main activity. You
   don't want to let the user wait if there's no reason. There are a
   few ways you can transfer the data to the main activity:

   a. Use intent extras when possible. If there are custom objects, you can
      serialize them using Gson for example, and deserialize them in your
      main activity.

   b. Save data in the application class/sharedpreferences
2. You can start getting data you will need later in your splash using another thread, but don't let the user wait when there isn't a
   good reason.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Can I populate a static variable from splash and use it in the main activity. Is it a bad way to pass data

Comment: Why not use intent extras?